# Get properties of a list of fitted models (objects)

Tags: fitting

If I do a fit, such as

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {x^a Cos[b x + c]}, {a,b,c} ,{x}]
```

then you return a `FittedModel` object, which has a list of properties. For example, I'd like to get a parameter list:

```
params = nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* a -> 0.0203318, b -> 3085.99, c -> 30.1162} *)
```

I want to run this command for all models generated in a list, and get a list of parameters. This can defs be done using commands like `Table`.

```
models = {nlm, ...}
Table[models[[i]]["BestFitParameters"],{i,1,Length[models]}]
```

Are there shorter hand ways of doing this? I'm aware of commands like

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
a /. x_ :> x^2
(* {1, 4, 9, 16} *)
```

However this didn't work when I tried applying it to the list of models to get parameters.

Comment: Please show the data to be fitted.

Comment: It was merely an example, the data I use is far too large to post here. You could generate some random data or make some up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[models[[i]]["BestFitParameters"],{i,1,Length[models]}]
```

can be shortened to

```
Table[m["BestFitParameters"], {m, models}]
```

or

```
#["BestFitParameters"]& /@ models
```

`{a->1, b->2, c->3}` can be converted to `{1,2,3}` with the [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) function.

Comment: `Through[models["BestFitParameters"]]` should also work.